# JInternalFrame and Keybinding

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jinternalframe

How do I bind a function key say(F11 etc) to a JInternalFrame, so it can activate a particular action.

I tried with the following

```
  this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F11"), new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               System.out.println("Called");
            }
        });
```

but it never gets called?
Or please suggest how to activate a button inside a JInternalFrame using function key.

Thanks
Azlam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, focus is never on the internal frame itself, focus is on a component on the internal frame.

So you should probably be adding the binding by using

internalFrame.getRootPane()....

You may also need to use

```
"WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT"
```

input map.

The blog entry on [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) explains this in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

`JInternalFrame` has troubles with `KeyListeners` and `KeyBindings`. To solve this problem try using `JDialog` instead of `JInternalFrame`.